Bijection involving the fundamental groupoid of a manifold
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. I read in this post, that there is a bijection between the fundamental groupoid $\Pi(M)$ and $(\tilde{M}\times \tilde{M})/\pi_1(M)$, where $\tilde{M}$ is the universal cover of $M$. We can define $\tilde{M}:=s^{-1}(x)$ and the universal covering map as $$[\gamma]\mapsto t(\gamma)$$ (where $s,t$ are the source and the target map of $\Pi(M)$). So I think that the bijection is the following
$$(\tilde{M}\times \tilde{M})/\pi_1(M)\to \Pi(M), \ \ \ [[\gamma],[\psi]]\mapsto [\gamma\ast \overline{\psi}]$$
where $\ast$ is the concatenation and $\overline{\psi}$ is the inverse path of $\psi$. The problem is that I cannot construct the inverse of this bijection. Could you help me?

You should explicitly say that by $\Pi(M)$ you mean the set of path homotopy classes in $M$ as in the answer you cite; this is not (quite) what $\Pi(M)$ usually means.

This is a purely algebraic fact about groupoids.  Suppose $G$ is a connected groupoid, with $H$ its set of morphisms, and fix an object $x$ of $G$.  Let $U$ be the set of morphisms with domain $x$ and let $A$ be the group of automorphisms of $x$, which acts on $U$ by precomposition.  Then I claim the map $F:(U\times U)/A\to H$ defined by $F([a,b])=ab^{-1}$ is a bijection (where $[a,b]$ is the equivalence class of $(a,b)\in U\times U$ under the action of $A$).
To prove $F$ is surjective, suppose $c:y\to z$ is a morphism; we must write $c$ as a composition $ab^{-1}$ for some $a:x\to z$ and some $b:x\to y$.  We can simply take $a$ to be an arbitrary morphism $x\to z$ (which exists since $G$ is connected) and $b=c^{-1}a$.
To prove $F$ is injective, suppose $a,b,c,d\in U$ are such that $ab^{-1}=cd^{-1}$; we must find a morphism $e:x\to x$ such that $c=ae$ and $d=be$.  We can take $e=a^{-1}c$; then obviously $c=ae$ and $be=ba^{-1}c=(cd^{-1})^{-1}c=d$.

Thank you very much! :)
